# Performance: log(a/b) vs. log(a) - log(b)

Tags: java, performance

I was wondering what is faster:

```
double value = Math.log(a) - Math.log(b);
```

or

```
double value = Math.log(a/b);
```

Could the way I calculate `value` have an impact on performance (Assume this gets called very often) or does the Java compiler optimize this for me?

Comment: There is a [related C++ question](also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858483/how-can-i-compare-the-performance-of-log-and-fp-division-in-c)

Comment: Carefully consider the context, here; there are many problems in which it is better to work in log-space throughout. If it is a single instance, I'd go for the division.

Comment: Why not just test it?

Comment: @BarrySW19 Results with micro machines like ours do not really deliver GOOD results when timing CPU speeds. What you should do is to try and find the O(n) of the algorythm.

Comment: It's hard to talk about impact on performance here, since we're talking about operations that may be going on on the FPU rather than the CPU... It's hard too say

Comment: Log is obviously slower than division

Comment: @DavidMerinos Ah, you want the theoretically correct answer rather than the actually correct answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always a good idea to profile and test, but `Math.log` is much more expensive than either `-` or `/`, so `Math.log(a/b)` (which calls `Math.log` only once) will, in principle, be faster than `Math.log(a) - Math.log(b)` (which calls it twice).

> Could the way I calculate `value` have an impact on performance (Assume this gets called very often) or does the Java compiler optimize this for me?

The compiler can't optimize that, no, because the two expressions are not equivalent. (Mathematically, it's true that ln <sup>*a*</sup>/<sub>*b*</sub> = ln *a* − ln *b*, but that's not necessarily true of floating-point numbers, since they are imprecise. And of course, `Math.log(-1) - Math.log(-1)` is `NaN`, making it quite different from `Math.log(-1 / -1)`.)

That said . . . you really need to test. Even if this gets called a lot, the difference between the two expressions will probably turn out to be negligible compared to (say) the cost of a nearby `println` that gets called almost as often. Your program would really have to run this expression an *extraordinary* number of times per second before you'd expect to observe a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I think `Math.log(a/b)` is faster. 
Why?

To solve `.log(x)` the compiler first resolves the value of `x` which is `a/b` in this case.

Thus, the steps to solve the `log` would be:

1. Solve `x`
2. Solve `a/b`

   3. Solve `a`
   4. Solve `b`
3. Return `a/b`
4. Return `log(a/b)`

On the other hand the substraction of logs would mean to `Solve x` 2 times (one for `a` and one for `b`. Then you'll have to resolve `x-y` with `x` and `y` being `.log()` operations.

However, Java could optimize all this for you.